C++ setup error I am using the Code Runner extension
I am trying to set up my vscode to work with c++ but when I run this
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World!";
    return 0;
}


I got this

C:/C++/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/C++/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib/libmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a-crtexewin.o): in function `main':
C:/M/B/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crtexewin.c:67:(.text.startup+0xbd): undefined reference to `WinMain'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status`your text`


What is the full commandline you're using? Please [edit] your question to include that.

This error happens when you are trying to build a Windows program instead of a Console program. How you tell Code Runner this I have no idea, but that is what the problem is.

Did you save the file before you compiled? Common issue in VSCode.

Code runner seems to cause a lot of problems, I'd recommend not using it and following the documentation instead

If you are using mac try to press the 3 dots on the top right corner and press run code. If you aren't try to insert using namespace std;, if that doesn't work try to restart or reinstall vscode or restart you computer.
Try this, but I am not the most expierienced at vscode configurations and extensions.

using namespace std is poor practice and definitely won't help with a linker error. Reinstalling vscode isn't likely to fix a configuration problem either
